# Should this sentence use “is ambitious” or “is ambition”?

Tags: nouns, adjectives

Which one of the following two sentences is correct? and why?

1. In my opinion, The characteristic that best describes me is **ambitious**. (adj.)
2. In my opinion, The characteristic that best describes me is **ambition**. (n.)

It is supposed to be the answer for this question:-

"what personal quality describes you most accurately?"

if we rearrange the sentences, we get this:-

**Ambitious** is the characteristic that best describes me?
**Ambition** is the characteristic that best describes me?

which form of the word should be used, noun or adjective?

Comment: Welcome to ELL. You will be more likely to receive a helpful answer if you first expand on the question? What information do you have already about whether a noun or an adjective should be used? What sources have you used so far to find the answer?

Comment: Probably both sentences could be improved if you stated what you wanted to say more directly. For example, "I am very ambitious," or, "I am full of ambition," or perhaps, "My biggest strength is my ambition."

Comment: it was a TOEFL question in the speaking section. the questions was as follows:-
"which characteristic describes you best?"
and i lead-in with the phrase "i think the charac...."
and left with this dilemma

Comment: Take out the "I think". Just go with: "The characteristic that describes me best is my ambition." If you're ambitious, then just say so – don't just state that you _think_ you're ambitious, assert that you _are_ ambitious.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed “the characteristic . . . is” calls for the noun, but the predicate “best describes me” rather better agrees with an adjective. I would re-engineer the sentence to get rid of this tension, on the grounds that characteristics do not *describe* us, adjectives (or descriptors) do; characteristics *characterize* us. “I think my chief characteristic is ambition” or “I consider myself to be chiefly characterized by ambition” are both more concise and avoid the dilemma.

Oh, and beware the Ides of March: “If it were so, it was a grievous fault, / And grievously hath Caesar answered it.”

Answer (score 1):

Ambition. Just imagine the sentence in its simplest form to know the right word:

> It is ambition.
>
> – What is?
>
> The characteristic is ambition.
>
> – What characteristic?
>
> The characteristic that best describes me.
>
> – Are you sure?
>
> No, I'm not sure, I just *think* that the characteristic that best describes me is ambition.